# How to create AWS RDS user using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform

I'm trying to create an application users for my Aurora RDS using Terraform. I can only find links for creating a [MySQL](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/mysql/r/user.html) user or a [Postgresql](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/cx57ja/how_do_i_create_a_user_and_database_only_after_a/) user but not a generic one for Aurora.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no generic 'Aurora RDS'.  There is 'Amazon Aurora with MySQL compatibility' or 'Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL compatibility'.

Comment: True that, but what my question is, "is their a generic approach that I can take to create an application user to use the Aurora RDS, using terraform, irrespective of whether I choose 'Aurora RDS with MySQL compatibility' or 'Aurora RDS with PostgreSQL compatibility'?"

Answer (score 0):

You can [use this provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs) to manage resources on already created RDS instance. If Your Aurora is postgresql compatible, every postgresql tool shall work with it.